# OpenGL ES: Bad performance when calculating vertex position in vertex shader

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I'm a beginner at OpenGL and I´m trying to animate a numer of "objects" from one position to another every 5 second. If I calculate the position in the vertex shader, the fps drops drastically, shouldn't these type of calculations be done on the GPU?

This is the vertex shader code:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexData;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 colourData;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normalData;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 personPosition;
layout(location = 4) in vec3 oldPersonPosition;
layout(location = 5) in int start;
layout(location = 6) in int duration;

layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform Matrices
{                       //base  //offset
    mat4 projection;    // 64   // 0
    mat4 view;          // 64   // 0 + 64   = 64
    int time;           // 4    // 64 + 64 = 128
    bool shade;          // 4    // 128 + 4 = 132    two empty slots after this
    vec3 midPoint;      // 16   // 128 + 16  = 144
    vec3 cameraPos;     // 16   // 144 + 16 = 160
                    // size = 160+16 = 176. Alligned to 16, becomes 176.
};

out vec3 vertexColour;
out vec3 vertexNormal;
out vec3 fragPos;

void main() {
    vec3 scalePos;
    scalePos.x = vertexData.x * 3.0;
    scalePos.y = vertexData.y * 3.0;
    scalePos.z = vertexData.z * 3.0;
    vertexColour = colourData;
    vertexNormal = normalData;

    float startFloat = float(start);
    float durationFloat = float(duration);
    float timeFloat = float(time);

// Wrap around catch to avoid start being close to 1M but time has         wrapped around to 0
    if (startFloat > timeFloat) {
        startFloat = startFloat - 1000000.0;
    }

    vec3 movePos;
    float elapsedTime = timeFloat - startFloat;
    if (elapsedTime > durationFloat) {
        movePos = personPosition;
    } else {
        vec3 moveVector = personPosition - oldPersonPosition;
        float moveBy = elapsedTime / durationFloat;
        movePos = oldPersonPosition + moveVector * moveBy;
    }

    fragPos = movePos;
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(scalePos + movePos, 1.0);
}
```

Every 5 second the buffers are updated:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->personPositionsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * this->persons.size() * 3, this->positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->personOldPositionsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * this->persons.size() * 3, this->oldPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->timeStartVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int) * this->persons.size(), animiationStart, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->timeDurationVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int) * this->persons.size(), animiationDuration, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I did a test calculating the positions on the CPU, and updating the positions buffer every draw call, and that doesn't give me a performance drop, but feels fundamentally wrong?

```
void PersonView::animatePositions() {
    float duration = 1500;
    double currentTime = now_ms();
    double elapsedTime = currentTime - animationStartTime;
    if (elapsedTime > duration) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this->persons.size() * 3; i++) {
            float moveDistance = this->positions[i] - this->oldPositions[i];
            float moveBy = (float)(elapsedTime / duration);
            this->moveByPositions[i] = this->oldPositions[i] + moveDistance * moveBy;
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->personMoveByPositionsVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * this->persons.size() * 3, this->moveByPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

On devices with better SOC:s (Snapdragon 835 etc) the framedrop isn't as drastically as on devices with midrange SOC:s (Snapdragon 625)

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, I can see that you're multiplying the projection and view matrices in the vertex shader, but there are no places where you rely on the view or projection matrix independently.

Multiplying two 4x4 matrices results in a very large amount of arithmetic calculations which are done for every vertex you're drawing. In your case - it seems you can avoid this all-together.

Instead of your current implementation - try multiplying the view and proj matrix outside of the shader, then bind the resulting matrix as a single viewProjection matrix:

```
Old:
gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(scalePos + movePos, 1.0);  

New:
gl_Position = projectionView * vec4(scalePos + movePos, 1.0);
```

This way, the proj and view matrix are multiplied once per frame, instead of once per vertex. This change should drastically improve performance - especially if you have a large amount of vertices.

Generally speaking, the GPU is indeed a lot more efficient then the CPU at performing arithmetic calculations like this, but you should also consider the amount of calculations. The vertex shader is executed per vertex - and should only calculate things that differ between vertices.

Performing a 1-time calculation on the CPU is always better than performing the same calculation on the GPU n-times (n = total vertices).

Comment: Totally agree.  Also wanted to point out that 90% of your operations can be aggregated into a single matrix (scale*3, translated by fixed, etc).  Another problem you are having is branching.  Anytime you have IF statements, you will slow down your shaders.  The CPU and GPU aren't competing, they are cooperating. If the CPU is faster at something, then use the CPU.  If the GPU is faster then use that.  You can calculate your move offsets on the CPU and bind them to another GL_ARRAY_BUFFER (avoid IF branching) but perform Matrix operations in the shader (faster on GPU).